# how to promisify socket.io Namespace.emit method

Tags: node.js, socket.io, promise, bluebird, eventemitter

i'm trying to understand and use promisification (bluebird) in nodejs

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8080);

var players = io.of('/players');
var coaches = io.of('/coaches');
var managers = io.of('/managers');

io.listen();
```

instead of doing this:

```
players.emit('name', data);
coaches.emit('name', data);
managers.emit('name', data);
```

i want to be able to write something like this:

```
var promises = 
    Array.of(players, coaches, managers)
         .map(function(nsp){
              return nsp.emitAsync('name', data)
          }); 

Promise.all(promises).then(function(){console.log('ok')});
```

is this even posible ?

Comment: just to clarify things, it doesn't matter if it is done using bluebird. i just need a way to promisify Namespace.emit method.